# CALCULATE with OR condition in two tables

Tags: powerbi, powerpivot, dax

In order to Sum the sales amount of blue products OR products that belong to category shoes, I'm using the following DAX expression:

```
CALCULATE(

SUM(Table[SalesAmount]),

FILTER(

Table,

Table[Color] = "Blue" ||

Table[Category] = "Shoes")

)
```

However, this doesn't work with two different tables (Colors and Categories), like:

```
CALCULATE(

SUM(Table[SalesAmount]),

FILTER(

Table,

Colors[Color] = "Blue" ||

Categories[Category] = "Shoes")

)
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the web led me to [this forum topic](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/RLS-rule-to-filter-on-multiple-tables-with-quot-OR-quot-logic/td-p/165249). Borrowing from OwenAuger's post, I propose the following formula:

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Table[SalesAmount]),
          FILTER(SUMMARIZE(Table, Colors[Color], Categories[Category]),
                 Colors[Color] = "Blue" ||
                 Categories[Category] = "Shoes"))
```

We get around the single table restriction by using `SUMMARIZE` to create a single table that has all of the pieces we need.

Comment: This is great. Another option is to use RELATED to avoid the restriction :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the ideal answer, but one way to do this is to use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Table[SalesAmount]), Colors[Color] = "Blue") + 
CALCULATE(SUM(Table[SalesAmount]), Categories[Category] = "Shoes") - 
CALCULATE(SUM(Table[SalesAmount]), Colors[Color] = "Blue", Categories[Category] = "Shoes")
```